# How can I get random items from a list and then remove them in dart

Tags: list, dart, random

How can I get random items from a String List and then remove in Flutter (dart),

Also, I need to copy the list to reset the system

I would like to know too if it's possible to call a variable with the String value from another variable

for example:

```
String house = 'x';

var listx = ['leo', 'pepe', 'juan', 'pedrito', 'jorgito'];


result = $list$house;
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'dart : math ' to generate random numbers using them as index you can remove strings from a list.

```
import 'dart:math';


void main() {
 
  
  var list=<String>["one","two","three","four"];
  
  var rand= new Random();
  
 //get the random string
  int i = rand.nextInt(list.length);
  String randomString=list[i];

 //print the random String

  print(randomString);

//remove the random string
  list.removeAt(i);

//print rest of the list
  print(list.toString());
  
}

// Console:
// four
// [one, two, three]
```

Comment: Did it help ? Please upvote or accept if it was helpful to you

Comment: Thanks! and how can I transform this string to a list?

 var juegoSelec = c;
 var paisLibreria = b;
 
 var cb = ['leo', 'pepe', 'jorge', 'tom', 'carl'];

 String get listActual => '$juegoSelec' + '$paisLibreria';


  List<String> list  = listActual; ??

Comment: If you want to convert a string to list , then you can do this :  var list =List<String>(); list.add(randomString);                                        if that what you want .

Comment: No, it doesn´t.

I tried with this:

 var juegoSelec = c;
 var paisLibreria = b;
 

String ca = '"["leo", "pepe", "juan", "pedrito", "jorgito"]"';

String cb = '["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]';

String get listActual => "$juegoSelec" + "$paisLibreria";

var transform = json.decode(listActual);

List list = transform;

and throw this error : Unexpected character (at character 1)

Comment: Its because there are syntax errors in your code , the string you passed in json.decode() is not a json string . I think you dont know dart syntax , first get atleast basic understanding of dart. Start here : https://dart.dev/guides/language , learn json here : https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json